# Java not showing some extended ASCII characters

Tags: java, ascii

Some extended ASCII characters such as 128 through 159 are not showing up in Java. Instead, they show up as blank characters. How can this be fixed?

Edit:
The following code,

```
for (int i = 157; i <= 163; i++) {
    System.out.print((char) i);
}
```

produces the output,

> ‎‎‎⁣⁣⁣[blank][blank][blank] ¡¢£

[blank] represents a blank character.

The first three characters are invisible. The fourth one is 160, which technically shows up because it is a non-breaking space character.

Comment: 157–159 are not ASCII characters.  They’re control characters in ISO-8859-* and Unicode, which don’t print anything. As far as I know, only the windows-12* character sets have glyphs for 158 and 159.

Comment: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl <- 157 is U+009D, looks like you're getting the expected output

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html <- java char is 16-bit and refers to UTF-16 code units, if you want ASCII or any other 8-bit code page, you may have to do some conversion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your code is correct** but the `System.out` stream does not use the extended ascii encoding. You need the `CP437` code table.

For example, your characters are correctly displayed using:

```
$ echo -e -n "\x9D\x9E\x9F\xA0\xA1\xA2\xA3" | recode CP437..utf8
¥₧ƒáíóú
```

(That is, are fine to be displayed)

You can force your Java program to use this:

```
$ java ... -Dfile.encoding=CP437 ...
```

Or you can use an stream with that encoding or directly to binary, for example:

```
try(FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/test.txt")) {
    int from = 157;
    int to = 163;
    byte [] xs = new byte[to - from + 1];
    for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        xs[i - from] = (byte) i;
    }
    fstream.write(xs);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

where the output is a correct **Extended ASCII** file:

```
$ recode CP437..utf8 /tmp/test.txt
$ cat /tmp/test.txt 
¥₧ƒáíóú
```

If you wish to convert that characters to Unicode at runtime, you can use:

```
for (int i = 157; i <= 163; i++) {
    System.out.print(new String(new byte[] {(byte)i}, Charset.forName("Cp437")));
}
```

with output

```
¥₧ƒáíóú
```

Answer (score 3):

Chars 157, 158 and 159 are [ISO control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters). They aren't supposed to be visible. You can check if character is control character by calling `isISOControl` helper method:

```java
Character.isISOControl((char) 157); // => true
```

> A character is [considered](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isISOControl(char)) to be an ISO control character if its code is in the range '\u0000' (0) through '\u001F' (31) or in the range '\u007F' (127) through '\u009F' (159).

Comment: He explicitly want display **extended ascii** code page (the CP437).